Can I have optional URL segments between hardcoded parts in Azure functions?
I have a problem that I need to implement url template using azure functions.
.../hardcoded_segment1/{dynamic_segment}/{optional_dynamic_segment?}/hardcoded_segment2
I have problem with the optional segment, as it is not optional at all, when I test it in postman.
I was thinking if there is a way to make it work as requested within one http trigger.
dynamic_segment has at the moment only 3 possibilities, and for one of them I need the second optional parameter.
I implement it in azure function http trigger v4 in js. I was asking GPT if it is wrong, but it claims it should work. I tried to find any documentation on that topic, but I couldn't.
const { app } = require('@azure/functions');

app.http('httpTrigger1', {
    methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
    route: 'v1/{segment1}/{segment2?}/bizdoc',
    authLevel: 'anonymous',
    handler: async (request, context) => {
        context.log(`Http function processed request for url "${request.url}"`);
        ...
        return { body: "test" };
    }
});

I have tried to move optional parameters to the end, then it works fine with one or both segments, but the solution was rejected and I have to met the requirements.
I also have been searching and I haven't seen anybody doing optional arguments between hardcoded segments.

Azure function doesn't support optional “middle” route parameter, you need to specify the optional parameters at the end. You can make use of Function proxies but its only supported for v3 functions refer https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/2047

There is nothing wrong in defining few triggers with different set of parameters. Trigger is just an entry point. When done right, it should have just one or few lines of code that call the logic from other place.


You need to set the optional parameter at the end of the URL because if you have set it in the middle then in the case of an empty value, your URL will break and will not continue further.
Either you can consider passing the optional parameter at the end or you can also pass it as a query parameter.
As Vlad DX commented, you can define the triggers with different set of parameters because the triggers acts as an entry point to the function.
If you are accessing these endpoints from Azure APIM then I would suggest you to use rewrite-uri policy.
Modify your code to below wherein the route would be v1/{segment1}/bizdoc/{segment2?} -

const { app } = require('@azure/functions');

app.http('httpTrigger1', {
    methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
    route: 'v1/{segment1}/bizdoc/{segment2?}',
    authLevel: 'anonymous',
    handler: async (request, context) => {
        context.log(`Http function processed request for url "${request.url}"`);
        ...
        return { body: "test" };
    }
});

